# Can't get basic Django setup working on VPS

Tags: python, django, centos, vps

I'm trying to deploy a Django website on a VPS (CentOS) and I'm running into problem right from start. Here is what I've done:

```
ssh root@myserver.com
cd /home/mydomain/public_html
pip install django
django-admin.py startproject mysite
cd mysite
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

When I visit `mydomain.com:8000` I expect to see the initial Django page "It worked!". But instead the browser just hangs and the connection times out.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: No, that should work. Try and wget http://127.0.0.1:8000 in that box. I would check firewall and iptables next if that works. CentOS is normally pretty locked down out of the box.

Comment: Have you checked your firewall?

Comment: @Victor'Chris'Cabral I get the correct "It worked!" page with `wget 0.0.0.0:8000`. What does that mean? Does it point to a firewall issue?

Comment: Either firewall or iptables. CentOS normally has locked down iptables. http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables#head-cdc2ff6985016368c04d0b37a5914eef2e8d5796

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using the django dev server on a remote host.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco I won't, I'm just testing some stuff.

Comment: @Victor'Chris'Cabral You were right, after opening the port I get the site working. If you post a response to this question I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cannot reach the site try the following:

```
$ wget http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

If you get a response locally but not through the network it could be a firewall or iptables issue. CentOS comes fairly locked down so check the ip tables.

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables#head-cdc2ff6985016368c04d0b37a5914eef2e8d5796